# MS SQL 2008 - Can I use Windows Authentication to connect from a Mac

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql, mac, windows-authentication

I have been using Navicat SQL on Mac (Snow Leopard) to connect to MS 2005 via "Basic Auth" and all is good.
However the DB is now being migrated to MS 2008 and try as I might I cant get on via Windows Auth.
I get the message...

[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
[FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source

Any Ideas would be v greatfuly accepted.
Many Thanks.

Comment: Is SQL Authentication not going to be supported on the new SQL 2008 server?

Comment: Have you considered a jumpbox/management server (security wise also more a best practice)

Comment: This might be helpful also: https://catbaba.com/connecting-to-sql-server-from-macos-using-windows-authentication-with-a-different-domain-account/

Answer (score 0):

Please note that Navicat needs to use NTLM for SQL Server connection. You can check the registry key value to see whether it supports responses. If it is set to 5, it will refuse NTLM responses.  See http://www.sqlpanda.com/2013/06/ntlmv2-and-freetds.html.